# Cannot load NDepend project file

Tags: ndepend

I am having troubles running NDepend from a NAnt task on a TeamCity build machine.
Here is the error I am getting:

```
[exec] ERROR:   The NDepend project file {D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\f5b78bbd49510fb2\myproject.ndproj} can't be loaded.
[exec] NDepend project file corrupted:The type initializer for 'NDepend.NDependServicesProvider' threw an exception.
[exec] ERROR:   The NDepend project file {D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\f5b78bbd49510fb2\myproject.ndproj} can't be loaded.
[exec] NDepend project file corrupted:The type initializer for 'NDepend.NDependServicesProvider' threw an exception.  Fatal error.
```

It runs OK on a dev machine. It actually also works with an older licenced version of ndepend (3.5.0.5374). I am currently using a newer version 5.3.0.8360 - still in evaluation period.

Comment: I figured it out. I ran the VisualNDepend.exe which prompted me to start the evaluation – apparently the server was not licensed to run the Ndepend console yet.
So the error that the project file was corrupted and can’t be loaded was misleading.

Comment: We just released NDepend v5.4 and in this situation (when starting NDepend.Console.exe without having activated the trial) a meaningful error description is shown to the user.